# Browserify adding namespace to Require

Tags: javascript, require, browserify

I have a fairly old code base that I need to Browserify. I would like it parse the require tree however all my requires have a namespace added to the like `myNameSpace.require('aModule')`. Is there anyway to tell it to look for `myNameSpace.require` instead of just `require()`?